# Probability family with two Children and sample spaces

Tags: probability

If we want to find the probability of a family with 2 children that has two boys we analyze the sample space $Ω_1=\{BB, BG, GB, GG\}$, so the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$.

But if we use the Sample Space $Ω_2 =\{0,1,2\}$ which shows the boys in the family, then the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$. I assume this is wrong because we don't count right the case {1} which includes both $\{BG,GB\}$.

My question now is:
a) In which cases can we use the second sample space? What kind of questions can we solve correctly that $Ω_1$ can't answer? Or is it just a wrong sample space to take at all?
b) If we already know that one child is boy then the probability in $Ω_1$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. Does this one has any relation to the second probability I find or is just a coincidence?

Comment: You can use $\Omega_1$ so long as you keep the right probability for the mixed case.  Of course, you've lost the order of the kids so you can't answer questions which depend on the order this way.

Comment: So, you say that questions with order cant answered by Ω2. Understood, so the same result was just coincidence? What I'm asking is if the probability of Ω1 for 2 children are boys when we already know that one child is, is the same with the probability of Ω2 that the family has 2 children boys = 1/3 .  Do they have any underlying relation?

Comment: I don't understand.  That question doesn't depend on order so you can use either sample space.

Comment: As a general rule, where possible,  I recommend sticking to equally probable events.  It just simplifies the computations.  Of course,  sometimes you really can't.

Comment: So we can answer the question " 2 children are boys when we know one already is" with the second space and the question "has 2 children boys"? Because despite the same result The questions seem different. That's why I'm troubled

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't understand your spaces.  Your $\Omega_2$ has the wrong probabilities.  The probability of getting $0$ or $2$ boys is $\frac 14$ each, while the probability of getting exactly $1$ boy is $\frac 12$.  Perfectly fine to use it, provided you get the probabilities right.

Comment: Ok! I can use the second space  just I need always to clarify that they are not equally like outcomes. I get it. Thanks!